# PaperJS multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have created a circle using paperJS now I am going to apply a undo option for the created circles. so how can I save `Point {x: 537, y: 157}`(this is event.point in paperjs) this into array.

Comment: You mean you need to clone it?

Comment: Suppose for example if i draw 3 circles i have to delete the second circle. how can i do this? I hope it is possible only by storing these points in array right.

Comment: @Devan If those points are objects, yes, you can keep them in an array. Notice how Object values are merely references to Objects, so you can keep the same Point in multiple arrays, etc.

Comment: @Šime Vidas can you give me an example in this case.

Comment: @Devan: Just `someArray.push(event.point)`. If nothing is modifying the point object, this will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the items to be removed from the screen, it is not as simple as removing them from your array because they will still be stored in the `children` array of whatever layer was active when they were created (`project.activeLayer` if you have not changed layers).

The following code creates three circles of different colors, stores them in an array, then splices the second circle out of the array, and finally removes it from the view ([jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/elofux/1/edit)):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/paperjs/paper.js/master/dist/paper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="p">
    var circleArray = [];
    circleArray.push(new Path.Circle({
        center: [20, 20],
        radius: 10,
        strokeColor: 'red'
        }));
    circleArray.push(new Path.Circle({
        center: [30, 30],
        radius: 10,
        strokeColor: 'green'
        }));
    circleArray.push(new Path.Circle({
        center: [40, 40],
        radius: 10,
        strokeColor: 'blue'
        }));
    var idOfItemToRemove = 1;
    var numberOfItemsToRemove = 1;
    var removeItems = circleArray.splice(idOfItemToRemove, numberOfItemsToRemove);
    for (var i = 0; i < removeItems.length; i++) {
        removeItems[i].remove();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="p" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The bin does not seem to work anymore so I created a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/pZA9T8MwEIb/yslLHTWK0o8phQF1YgIBW5rBda6NVceuzk4RqvLfcT6GgDpU4O2e13qf012ZETWyjL2f0MuKxUzaspsvgkAqkhqfiMQXPEJebHZmgpJz4ypu8BNeha+SbZ/w685AeBKNR8ogX6YxLNMiHjCJUjUug0U6AufJnnBrtQ2fZ4TlbOBtFP3Ftgq21b22IyGa//nWwbe+17fXDf7QdTdW5cvh2WP9Yd+wthcMh16MkWnqPdIQuxs59aBPA53u7s5aSeS/u+Pbld0qB0vAVahJN6DgYdqdaDRHXwU+n0cwXmCS56pIhpF3TS1rvwE=)